# Taking advantage of an "Intel Turbo Memory" card for swap or fast bootup

Tags: 11.04, thinkpad, swap

I have an X61 thinkpad (currently running 10.10) that I purchased 3 years ago. I splurged a little and got a [Turbo Memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_Memory) expansion to improve my windows boots.

When I installed 10.04 (and subsquently upgraded to 10.10) there was no Turbo Memory support and there's an *awful* lot of noise on searches.

1) **Is there any support for Intel Turbo Memory in 11.04 or trivially compilable into the kernel as swap, suspend, hibernate point, or boot partition?**

2) **If there is, should I bother trying to use it?**

Answer (score 1):

You might look at `lspci` and see if you can identify the device and see if there is a driver bound to it.  If there is a driver for it and it presents a block device, then you should be able to use it for swap/hibernation.  If there isn't, then you're out of luck.

Comment: I get: `02:00.0 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Turbo Memory Controller (rev 01)`

Comment: Add `-v` and see if it lists a kernel module or driver under that device.

Comment: `02:00.0 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Turbo Memory Controller (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Intel Corporation Turbo Memory Controller
 Physical Slot: 2
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
 Memory at dfcffc00 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
 I/O ports at 2000 [size=128]
 [virtual] Expansion ROM at dfe00000 [disabled] [size=64K]
 Capabilities: <access denied>
`

Comment: You need to run it with sudo, and look for a line about kernel driver or module.  Trying to paste the full results won't fit.

Comment: Thanks. No, there don't seem to be any lines that start with `kernel` unlike the SATA controller.

Answer (score 1):

**Not at present**

Digging through a search on `02:00.0 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Turbo Memory Controller (rev 01)`, it looks like I'm SOL as respect to [bug 312380](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/312380) where support for this as block device is concerned.

A request to make this useful seems to be stuck in limbo [here](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/12409/).

Lesson: don't expect windows-specific low-use hardware to be useful in other operating systems.